# Why the output directory of my project cannot be changed in vs 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am trying to change the output diretory of my project with microsoft visual studio. In my project properties window, i changed the output dir from:

```
$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\
```

to:

```
$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\bin\
```

But it doesn't work, even the "apply" button is disable.

Comment: What type of project is it?

Comment: win32 conslole application

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I edit my project.vcxproj file!